# How to transfer form data from one html page to another?

Tags: php, web-development-server

I have a registration page, having 3 columns username, email, and password. Login Page, consisting of 2 columns email and password now I want to show the username of the corresponding email while logging into the page.
Note- I just want to know how can I fetch the value entered in email to another page.

Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Change the action attribute of the form.

Comment: you haven't shown any code.

Answer (score 1):

you can get user information like this

```
sessionService.loadUser().then(user => console.log(user));
```

Answer (score 0):

you could do this:

**page1.php:**

```
<form action="page2.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" />
    <input type="text" name="surname" />
    <input type="button" value="Click Me">
</form>
```

Then once you submit the form the file page2.php will receive the form field values in this way;

**page2.php**

```
if($_POST){
    var_dump($_POST);
}
```

good luck!

Comment: i want the page 2.php's data to an html page

Comment: then you need to format the php data in order to display them inside your HTML tags